# How can I display lvl1 options in a separate container?

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

A widget of mine is defined like so:

```
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hierarchicalMenu({
    container: '#hierarchical',
    attributes: ['region.lvl0', 'region.lvl1'],
    cssClasses: {
      active: 'active'
    },
    templates: {
      item: menuTemplate
    }
  })
);
```

This leads to a navigation display like so:

```
region.lvl0
region.lvl0 (selected)
    > region.lvl1
    > region.lvl1
    > region.lvl1
region.lvl0
region.lvl0
```

Is it possible to render lvl1 facets in a separate container? For instance, lvl0 is displayed in a list format. When a user selects a lvl0 region, a dropdown populates with lvl1 facets in a separate area to refine their search even further.

If that isn't possible, is it possible to get the current lvl1 attributes and to manually send a query to algolia with a new attribute (similar to algolia search helper)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [connectors](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/connectors.html) that encapsulate all the logic needed for making search widgets. You'll have to provide a function in order to get the rendering that you'd like to see.